# Finding all maximally-matchable edges in a bipartite grah sage

Tags: sagemath

Has anyone coded of the algorithm given by Tassa, Tamir. "Finding all maximally-matchable edges in a bipartite graph." Theoretical Computer Science 423 (2012): 50-58 in **Sage** ?

Comment: Please, could you provide a link to (a preliminary version of) this paper? Or explain briefly how this algorithm works?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397511010474

Comment: Above is the link of the paper. Problem is: In a bipartite graph (V1,V2,E) where |V1| is not equal to |V2|, I need to find the edges which not common in any maximum matching. @Taroccoesbrocco

Comment: Thanks for your time @Taroccoesbrocco I got a different approach to solve my problem still it would be helpful if you can code Algorithm 3 of the above mentioned paper.